# Bind Specific Nested Datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datalist, nested-datalist

I am using nested Datalist.
Now, I want to bind specific inside datalist based on dropdown value selection. I am able to bind all inside datalist but not only one specific.

For i.e.,

Main and Nested Datalist is as below :

.NET <-main datalist
      C#    <-nested datalist
      vb
Java
     1
     2

Now, .NET and Java both contains dropdown. If user select value c# from .NET dropdown then I want to bind only nested datalist of .NET, means only display c# or say based on dropdown condition. And if now, user select 1 from Java then it show only 1 but .NET is showing c# only which must not be changed untill user filter .NET dropdown.

Please help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If DropDown is in Main DataList then dropdown even can be catched in the "DataList1_ItemCommand" event and in this even check the command name and argument, find the nested datalist with findcontrol method of main datalist. Bind the nested DataList   according to condition.

1) MainDataList_ItemCommand 
2) Check the command name and emphasized textargument
 3) Find the nested Datalist
 4) Perform filteration    on the basis of selected value of dropdown
 5) Bind the nested    Datalist.

Comment: It is not firing Datalist_ItemCommand and most important think, there is no property Command Name and Argument for dropdownlist.